# Why did she bring flowers to the tomb?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-missing-tv

In the second season of the BBC TV Series [**The Missing**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3877200/), the narration constantly shifts backwards and forwards in time. It is not hard to follow, but it makes it harder, at least for me, to keep track of all the details.

There's one "inconsistency" that keeps bugging me about the story and for which I have been unable to find an answer yet. There are spoilers ahead, of course, so if you're planning on watching the series my advise would be to see it before reading what comes next.

In episode 4 of the series (**[Statice](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b08226yr)**) we learn that Sophie (aka Alice), who is supposed to "lay low" because she's in the process of staging her own death and has the police and her parents looking for her, finds the time to shop for some flowers and deliver them to the tomb of Henry Reed.

At this moment, if I recall correctly, there's nothing that links Sophie to the "suicidal" Reed, so this is a fundamental clue that allows Detective Baptiste to connect the death of the English officer to the disappearing of Alice Webster and Sophie Giroux and carry on with his investigation.

Later in the final episode, [**The Mountain**](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b084l0x7), we learn how Sophie met Henry Reed for the first time when he was blackmailed by Adam Gettrick into trying to perform a surgery on Sophie. Henry refuses at first but then, threatened by Adam at gunpoint, pretends to help him. This encounter between Sophie and Henry doesn't last more than a few minutes and they don't even speak with one another. Also, since Henry will be later killed by Adam, he won't even be able to save Sophie's life and will force Adam to change his plans and let Sophie be cured in a hospital, at great risk to be discovered.

Considering that Sophie seems to loathe the other officer (Adrian Reed) involved together with Reed and Gettrick in the killing of the little girl in Iraq in 1991, ***why would she bring flowers to Reed's tomb***?